# Need to disable social sharing buttons on my downloaded image

Tags: orangedox

I need to disable the social sharing buttons that appear when my file is downloaded, it's not supposed to be shared by the user. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, right now that functionality is only available in our Business product, where you can create custom-branded viewers, and choose which (if any) social channel sharing options you'd like to make available.  There is also a work-around if you select "Enable Direct Download" in the PRO product:  http://orangedox.com/pricing/

Hope this helps!